# RegExp поиск и замена строки в проекте

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

В проекте нужно найти и заменить цифры внутри строки и т.к. я не очень то знаком с регулярными выражениями, прошу помочь составить его (уже все примеры перепробовал но не получается).

В исходниках имеется строки такого типа (шаблон строки целиком вместе с кавычками):

> "\n239238207"

где число постоянно разное, надо найти во всех файлах похожие строки.
Во всех файлах нужно найти похожие строки, получить само число **239238207** и заменить его на нужное, число не всегда одинаковое!

Для поиска и быстрой замены использую notepad++. Необходимо составить, правильное, регулярное выражение, для поиска и замены.

Comment: Число найти просто: /\d+/, строка типа "\n239238207" определяется выражением /"\n\d+"/  Хотелось бы уточнить, на какие числа их нужно заменять?

Comment: подойдет? :
`preg_replace('/\n(\d{9})/ms', '[заменить на]', text-источник)`

Comment: в данном примере все равно на какие числа. Спасибо ваш метод помог, оформите его в виде ответа. Но есть небольшая поправка перед \n нужно добавить еще \. в итоге будет так /"\\n\d+"/. И подскажите как будет правильно если нужно перечислить допустимые символы? Что то типа /"\\n(.[0-9])"/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет?
`preg_replace('/\\n(\d{9})/', '[заменить на]', text-источник)`

Можно более подробно сделать....
Например
`preg_replace('/\\n([0-2]{2}\d{3}[5-8]{4})/', '[заменить на]', text-источник)`

это заменит
\n
за которым следуют [2 цифры от 0 до 2 включительно],
за которыми следуют [любые три цифры],
за которыми следуют [4 цифры от 5 до 8 включительно]

т.е. `\n229995678` сработает
а `\n329995678` не сработает

Comment: Автору такая регулярка подойдет для блокнота++, но если использовать в preg_replace, то должно быть `/\\\\n(\\d{9})/ms` . Баг Вашего выражения заключен в необходимости двойного экранирования бэкслэша, которое не выполнено. Дошедшее до движка регексов выражение будет таким: `\n(\d{9})` то есть просто перевод строки, а должно быть `\\n(\d{9})`, то есть бэкслэш и символ `n`.

Comment: В плане слешей тут всё отлично, так как использованы одинарные кавычки, но вот модификатор `/m` тут не нужен, т.к. в выражении отстутствуют `^` и `$`, которые он переопределяет. `/s` тут тоже  не нужен, т.к. в выражении нет точки.